# Save answers of the current user to show later on (NO USERS) RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a survey app where people can answers questions. Based on their answer they see a personalized show page. For instance if the question is `'What is your name?'` and the answer is `'Bob'`, i wan't to be able to display `'Hi there Bob'` on the show page.

Now it's very important that users don't have to login, so now i'm thinking about whether i should store all the answers in the session or i should save everything to the database. And if i save it to the database how do i do something like `current_user.name` if there are no users. Showing the data of the current user in the show page seems impossible to me without actually having users.

What would be the best solution here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Without users don't have to login, how would you show the individual name on the page?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i want to know, and it's not just one question, there are 50+ questions, so saving them in the session seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the info in the database using `session.id` as a key. This way, users don't have to login, the session cookie is not bloated, but, of course, when the cookie is not there (deleted, another browser, etc), you can't find user's info.

Comment: And how would you show the current users name on the show page for example?

Comment: @luissimo: what do you mean? You fetch it from the database by session id.

Comment: @luissimo: you know what? Store everything in the session and then store the _session_ in the database (activerecord session store)

Comment: May i ask how you add session.id to a existing table and pass the session_id to it through a form?

Comment: @luissimo: `session.id` is just a string, you store in the database like any other value. Also, you don't need to pass it in a form, it's available automagically in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Storing information in the session ensures that when the user returns, you know who they are, unless they have deleted session variables.

This could be your fail back: I understand you don't want users to have a login, but how about a unique identifier per survey which you could provide the user with when they "Save for later"? Upon returning, you could ask them for the unique identifier previously issued to them. You could also send an email to the user when they "Save for later". The email could contain a link, which in turn would contain a parameter identifying the survey uniquely.